# Import numpy in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matlab-engine

I'm working with python in matlab and I'm trying to import numpy but I can't.

First I created an env in conda:

```
conda create -n matlab python=3.7 numpy
```

Then I set it in matlab prompt:

```
pyversion('C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab\python.exe')
>> pyenv

ans = 

  PythonEnvironment with properties:

          Version: "3.7"
       Executable: "C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab\python.exe"
          Library: "C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab\python37.dll"
             Home: "C:\Users\Familia\.conda\envs\matlab"
           Status: NotLoaded
    ExecutionMode: InProcess
```

Then when I try to see if I have numpy I got this:

```
>> help('numpy')
```

> numpy not found.
>
> Use the Help browser search field to search the documentation, or type
> "help help" for help command options, such as help for methods.

and If I try

```
py.importlib.import_module('numpy')
```

I got this:

[image]

**What I missed?**

Comment: Try activating your conda environment and installing ```numpy``` via ```pip install numpy```

Comment: Are you able to use ```numpy``` outside matlab?

Comment: @EnriqueBet yes, I'm using numpy in Spyder and Jupyter

Comment: @EnriqueBet I did what you said, but still getting the same error in matlab

Comment: The string `"Impossível localizar o módulo especificado"`  appears to be the Portuguese localisation of the message in Windows which in English is `"The specified module could not be found"`.  This seems to be some kind of error related to DLL loading.

Comment: @alaniwi yes, it says that the original error was DLL load failed

Comment: I assume, according to the message, that you need to check your numpy version